# byte[] to String and String to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting, byte

I have a small problem to change the type from `byte[]` to `String` and then from `String` to `byte[]`. When I use my code, it returns the RSA error "Too much data for rsa block". But when I use the original `byte[]`, it works fine.

This is how it works:

```
cipherData = cipher.doFinal(cipherData);
```

I tried to change the data type:

```
// Byte[] to String
String encrypted = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
// RSA Operation
cipherData = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes());
```

Comment: I don't understand. The line `String encrypted = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8")` is not going to have any effect on the line `cipherData = cipher.doFinal(cipherData)`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Changed it. But the error persists. I tried it also with StringBuffer. It does not work as well.

Comment: Have you tried specifying character set explicitly:  `encrypted.getBytes("UTF-8")` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
String encrypted = new String(cipherData, "UTF-8");
```

Your `cipherData` *isn't* UTF-8-encoded text. It's arbitrary binary data. So don't try to interpret it as if it *were* UTF-8 text.

Instead, use either hex or base64 - where base64 is probably the simplest approach. I like the [public domain iHarder base64 library](http://iharder.net/base64):

```
String encrypted = Base64.encodeBytes(cipherData);
...

cipherData = Base64.decode(encrypted);
```

EDIT: If you're using Android of course, then use the [built-in library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) :)

Comment: Why would you use iHarder and not the built in support of the Convert class?

Comment: If I would like to use such a library, i have to take a look at Android  Base64 libraries. Does the library also support decryption?

Comment: Thanks. I will check the API for Base64 on Android.

Comment: @MrMoDoJoJr: Are you thinking of System.Convert in .NET? This is Java.

Answer (score 0):

I works perfect. Here is the Code for Android Base64 library:

```
String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(cipherData, Base64.DEFAULT);
cipherData = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT));
```